# Disabling Word-Wrap in XCode

Tags: xcode, xcode4, text-editor

I'd like to disable the Word-Wrap "feature" in XCode.  Can this be done?  I can't find a setting or a hotkey that will do this.

Also, before stating "long lines of code are bad-- keep them short and format the wrapping yourself", please realize two things.

First, I often keep multiple code pages open for reference, so they are each pretty small.  Second, I am using XCode strictly as an editor for an existing, embedded systems project.  I didn't write most of this code and much of it is 80+ characters wide because of heavy use of code indention.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is moved (at least as of) Xcode 12.4:
Xcode > Preferences > Text Editing > Display > Wrap lines to editor width

Answer (score 23):

I think that you are searching for the checkbox under *Preferences>Text editing>Indentation>Wrap lines to editor width*.

Comment: This is now under Display not Indentation

Answer (score 7):

Main Menu > Xcode > Preferences..., select Text Editing tab. Select Indentation sub tab. Uncheck Line Wrapping.

Answer (score 3):

In Xcode 11 you can achieve it by checking `Wrap lines` with in the Xcode.

**Step 1:**

Select file inspector

[image]

**Step 2:**

Under Text setting check *Wrap lines*

[image]

Hope it will help someone Using latest Xcode.

Comment: This seems to overwrite the Xcode preferences. I would recommend to use the personal Xcode settings, because not everyone would want to view this file in the same wrapping/non-wparring style.